# Scenekit How to curve/warp/bend a tile around a globe / sphere

Tags: shader, scenekit

I want to create a Sphere (Earth) with several Tiles laying on it like the following screenshot. (Wireframe of every vertex from CesiumJs)

So basically I split up the surface of earth in several smaller tiles that have to somehow follow the curvature of a sphere.

**How do I morph/warp/bend a single tile like this?**
The only idea I have so far is mimicing the look through several points in between (the more triangles the smoother the look).

Is there any shader I can use for this problem or other ideas?

Thanks so much for any help.

[image: Cesium JS Tiles]

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, one possible method is to use the predefined resource (flyweight pattern).

However, using such a method or manual drawing still need the projection such as represent points as (lat, long) coordinates.

[image: Earth projection]

Using shader will not help with the interaction afaik.